# Why does JSON returned from the django rest framework have forward slashes in the response?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

My response code

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json
responseData = { 'success' : True }
return Response(json.dumps(responseData))
```

How it appears on doing `curl` or accessing the response through the browser.

```
"{\"success\": true}"
```

Why the forward slashes? How do I remove them?

Comment: That's doubly encoded JSON; a JSON string encoding a JSON object. Are you sure you don't have anything else encoding the response **again**?

Comment: The Response function I am using is by the django rest framework.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are rendering the data to JSON **twice**. Remove your `json.dumps()` call.

From the [Django REST documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/):

> Unlike regular `HttpResponse` objects, you do not instantiate `Response` objects with rendered content. **Instead you pass in unrendered data, which may consist of any Python primitives.**

The Django REST framework then takes care of producing JSON for you. Since you gave it a string, that string was JSON encoded *again*:

```
>>> import json
>>> responseData = { 'success' : True }
>>> print json.dumps(responseData)
{"success": true}
>>> print json.dumps(json.dumps(responseData))
"{\"success\": true}"
```

The framework uses [*Content Negotiation*](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/) to determine what serialisation format to use; that way your API clients can also request that the data is encoded as YAML or XML, for example.

Also see the [*Responses* documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/):

> REST framework supports HTTP content negotiation by providing a `Response` class which allows you to return content that can be rendered into multiple content types, depending on the client request.