# ajax json : how to retrieve data from json object received by ajax?

Tags: json, ajax, django

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: MyURL,
  method: 'GET',
  processData: true, 
  contentType: 'application/json;',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) { 
    alert("Success data= "+JSON.stringify(data));
    var count = Object.keys(data).length;
    alert("count = "+count );
    result=data[0];
    alert("result.CountryName:"+ result.CountryName);
    alert("total " + keys.length + " keys: " + keys);
  error: function(data) { alert("ajax Error");   },
});
```

The 1st alert seems ok and gives:
Success data= "[{\"CountryName\": \"france\", \"Currency\": \"Euro\", \"PriceMax\": 500.00, \"PriceStep\": 50.00, \"PriceMin\": 100.00}]"

From the firebug/network/response i see the same data (with the backslash!!)

The 2nd alert gives 107. Apparently each character is an object ?
But when i check the syntax on http://jsonlint.com/ the json is correct.

Finally the last alert gives: undefined.

So what is wrong  ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The data you're sending is an array containing a single object. You'll need to use `data[0]['CountryName']`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change the result                alert("data[CountryName]:"+data[0]['CountryName']); --> undefined
alert("data.CountryName:"+ data[0].CountryName);--> undefined
Thank you Daniel

Comment: Seems like the data is not being interpreted as JSON; you'll need to manually parse it with `JSON.parse(data)` first.

Answer (score 0):

The response that you have is not an JSON object, it is a String. So you need to parse it to a JSON and then take the first position of the array.

```
json_data = JSON.parse(data)
result = json_data[0]
```

and then you use a property of that object:

```
result.CountryName
```

Comment: Hi, thank Rubico. I correct the code but it does not change the result. I am wondering why i have count = 107 ?

Comment: I'm almost sure that you are getting the data as a String and not as a Json. Now I'm sure that is a String, I made a test and the string has exactly 107 of length.

Comment: Did u tried to `console.log(data)` as Daniel said on a comment below, maybe you should use `JSON.parse(data)` to parse your string to a JSON before

Comment: Hi Rubico, i set  dataType: "json", so the ajax request answer with a json object. My problem was early in my django code. Thank you Rubico

Comment: alvaro, can you make a test? Try `console.log(data)` and see if it is an array with an object or a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the slash in the json string.

I read [Why does JSON returned from the django rest framework have forward slashes in the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249491/why-does-json-returned-from-the-django-rest-framework-have-forward-slashes-in-th) and make some modif in my django code.

i changed     return JsonResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), safe=False)
to     return JsonResponse(data, safe=False) and the slash disappeared then the javascript code worked.

Thanks for your help Daniel and Rubico