# How to convert Python List of numbers to json object

Tags: python, json

I want to convert python list of numbers to a json object.
input:

```
input is a number like 22
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "budget" : 22
}
```

Comment: This would not be valid JSON as the ```"budget"``` key is a duplicate.

Comment: if I've just one number in list .. like.. input x=[1], output = {"budget": 1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have duplicate keys in a "valid" json object.

Your best bet would be to convert your list into a Python dict like so, and then convert it into a JSON object:

```
import json

my_list = [22, 30, 44, 55] # Your starting list

python_dict = {"budget": my_list}  # Python dict

json_obj = json.dumps(python_dict)  # Convert python dict to JSON obj
```

Comment: json key is coming like \"budget\" : 1 instead of "budget" : 1

Comment: @Rahul where is it "coming" like that?

Comment: in the json returned by api call

Comment: It is probably because you are using some sort of Rest Framework that is converting it to JSON a second time. If that's the case, then try removing the last step where you convert the `python_dict` to `json_obj`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249491/why-does-json-returned-from-the-django-rest-framework-have-forward-slashes-in-th

Comment: thank you so much man, really new to python django and it's giving me real tough to do small stuffs

Comment: No problem! It's always rough to learn something new, but it always gets easier and more fun. If this answered your question, you can press the "Check" mark on the left side of the correct answer to show the solution was found for anyone else having a similar issue. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not valid JSON since you can't have duplicate keys.

What you could do instead is have something along the lines of:

```
{
    "budget": [22, 30, 44, 55]
}
```

This can be achieved as follows:

```
import json

json_object = json.dumps({"budget": my_list})
```

Comment: thanks Rayan. Sorry my bad, JSON can't have duplicate keys